# Application cannot be uploaded to the device

Tags: ios, xamarin, code-signing, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I'm trying to upload my app to an iPhone. I've developed this app on the simulator up until this point but now I need the ability to receive remote notifications as well as universal links. Since remote notifications are incompatible with the simulator, I need to provision this iPhone 7 in order to test.

Whenever I attempt to the deploy the app to the phone, this happens:

```
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
CopyingFile - PercentComplete: 99%
CreatingStagingDirectory - PercentComplete: 5%
ExtractingPackage - PercentComplete: 15%
InspectingPackage - PercentComplete: 20%
TakingInstallLock - PercentComplete: 20%
PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30%
InstallingEmbeddedProfile - PercentComplete: 30%
VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of
```

/private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xJmSvP/extracted/App.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/kyleformeck/sinum/App.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/App.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone 7': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

Application could not be uploaded to the device.

**Relevant Device Log Info:**

```
Error (219) / streaming_zip_conduit: Failed to install application at <private> : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394, LegacyErrorString=<private>, SourceFileLine=199, FunctionName=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
```

I've tried several different ways to fix this issue and nothing seems to work.

I tried the manual way:

1. In the Apple developer portal, I created a new Explicit App ID in which I appended .dev to end. i.e. com.company_name.vnext.ios.app_name.dev.
2. I chose the Team ID as the App ID prefix.
3. I add the entitlements I needed, Associated Domains and Push Notifications and then clicked Register.
4. Before I created the new provisioning profile, I edited the App ID created above so I can configure the notification certificates. So I clicked Edit and created a new Development SSL certificate by using Keychains 'Request Certificate from a Certificate Authority' and uploading that certificate to the app dev portal. Then I downloaded an installed the new IOS Push Services certificate.
5. Then I created my new provisioning profile by walking through the steps; I chose iOS App Development as the type, selected the new App ID I just created that includes all the new entitlements I need, selected my existing dev certificate, selected the new iPhone 7 that I previously added to our account by registering it's UDID. I then downloaded and installed that provisioning profile.

I know the installation of the provisioning profile worked because before I did this, again, for the 10th time this week, I deleted all the existing provisioning profiles in \Library\MobileDevice\Provisioning Profiles

I've also tried the Fastlane way after manually creating the new App ID with appropriate entitlements (all relevant data was placed into the matchfile).

```
fastlane nuke development
fastlane match init
fastlane match development
```

This is what my Entitlements.plist file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:<supported_URL_scheme></string>
    </array>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also made sure that my Provisioning Profile is the one I just created and Custom Entitlements is the Entitlements.plist file shown above.

**Environment Info**

```
MacOS Mojave v10.14.4
XCode v10.2 (10E125)
Visual Studio for Mac v8.0.1 (build 1)
Xamarin.iOS v12.6.0.25
iPhone 7 running iOS 12.1.4 (16D57)
```

Comment: I actually found a way around this issue, it was to remove the beta-reports-active key. However, I still need this key for distribution builds. Is it not possible to use this key on development builds?

Comment: There is no need to add beta-reports-active key under development. You won't use testflight to test it since it is under development builds.